# Get one to many relation data

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I am having three tables.

1. Customer(list of customers)
2. Payments(list of customer payment)
3. Orders(list of customer orders)

customer can have more than one payment and order that is one to many relation.

I tried following query but it is not showing proper result.

```
select a.name, b.job_date as JobDate, c.order_date as OrderDate from Customers a
inner join Jobs b on a.id = b.customer_id
inner join Orders c on a.id = c.customer_id
where a.id = 1;
```

What i need is to show a customer's orders and jobs.

Comment: need more information. What are you getting? what are you trying to get?

Comment: I need payment details and job details of a customer

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired outcome for your query based on it to illustrate your question?

Comment: You need to tell the structure and/or sample data for your application. For instance you've named `Jobs` table in your query but you didn't mention its aim or structure.

Comment: and which DBMS are u using? and where are u using ur payment table

Comment: I am having my screen shot but without 10 reputation I cant post?

Comment: Keep in mind that combining one-to-many joins will give you a lot of results, as each row in Jobs will be matched with each row in Orders. Unless there is a relation between Jobs and Orders, two separate queries (one for Jobs, another for Orders) would be easier.

Comment: Yes right this is what exactly I am tying to express. But i don't have any relations for jobs and orders. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: If there is no relation between Jobs and Orders why not show them in different results?

Comment: @RelicSet upload  your screenshot to any sharing service and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

Try left join instead of inner join. child tables might not have records assosiated with Customers.id =1.

```
select a.name, b.job_date as JobDate, c.order_date as OrderDate from Customers a
left join Jobs b on a.id = b.customer_id
left join Orders c on a.id = c.customer_id
where a.id = 1;
```

Comment: No change results same number of row as in inner join

Comment: so you are getting some rows, rt? then what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the orders you can use the following :

```
select a.name, c.order_date as OrderDate from Orders c 
inner join Customers a on a.id = c.customer_id
where a.id = 1;
```

You get build a similar query to get all the employee's jobs:

```
select a.name, b.job_date as JobDate from Jobs b 
    inner join Customers a on a.id = b.customer_id
    where a.id = 1;
```